# Orderby clause in Entity relationship using spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entity class as follows.

**Clasz** entity

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "CLASZ")
    public class Clasz implements Serializable {        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="CZ_ID")
        private Integer id;
        
        private String name;}
```

**Student** Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="S_ID")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "S_NAME")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "S_AGE")
    private int age;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CZ_ID")
    private Clasz classz;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAT_ID")
    @NotNull
    private List<Category> category;
    
    @Column(name = "S_DESCR")
    private String description; 

//  constructor / getter and Setter    }
```

**Category** Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CAT_ID")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "CAT_NAME")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "CAT_DESCRI")
    private String description; 

}
```

I have a StudentRepository interface which extends JPARepository.
To find All the student details by class id and the result should be ordered by category name.
I wrote a method like `findAllByClaszIdOrderByCategoryNameAsc(int classId).`

Comment: can you clarify the expected output of the query? do you want "all student associated with category catId"?

Comment: Yes and it should be ordered by category name.

Comment: I don't understand this last part, if the method returns a `List<Student>` of students that are a associated with one category, how can the list be ordered by category name?

Comment: Yeah Correct. I made a mistake in the code. I will update soon. Give me 10 mins.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi I have just updated my code. The actual class names are different and while creating the example code I made a mistake. Now it is correct. I wanted to find all Students by class id and the record should be ordered by Category name.

Comment: Now I removed 'By' which is there before the OrderBy in the jpa repo method and it is giving error no property found category.name

Comment: what is the return type of `findAllByClaszIdOrderByCategoryNameAsc(int classId)`?

Comment: Optional<Student>

Comment: @MarcoLucidi Any idea , or do you think better to go with native query ?

Comment: I still don't understand how can a single student (`Optional<Student>`) be "ordered by category name". or do you mean the category list inside the Student Entity (`List<Category> category`) be ordered by name? if that's the case, look for `@OrderBy` annotation, you can add it along with your `@OneToMany` to specify order.

Comment: Ok let me check that part once.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi    what I am expecting is the result of select * from Student a, Clasz b , Category  c where  a.cls_id=b.cls_id and  b.cls_id=? orderby c.cat_name       <--- this is not possible ?